# Code for checking if input is palindrome always returns True

Tags: python, python-2.x

my code is only ever returning true...

```
import string

def palendrone():
    input = raw_input('give us some stuff and we will see if it is a palendrone;')
    lowercase = string.lower(input)
    new_string = ''
    markList = [".", " ", ";", ":", "!", "?", "/", "," , "#", "@", "$", "&", ")", "(", "\", '*', '^'"]

    for mark in (lowercase):
        if mark in lowercase:
            new_string += ''

    backwards_string = new_string[::-1]
    print backwards_string
    print new_string

    return backwards_string == new_string
```

basically the code is supposed to return true if a phrase is a palindrome and false if it is not... but it always returns true.

Comment: Umm... wat? `for mark in (lowercase): if mark in lowercase:`

Comment: the best way to filter out a list of single characters like that is with `str.translate`. In Python3 this works slightly differently, but in Python2 you can just do `new_s = old_s.translate(None, characters_to_be_deleted)`. Since the `string` module has handy pre-built strings, it's even easier. `new_s = old_s.translate(None, string.punctuation+string.whitespace)`

Answer (score 1):

Your program is returning `True` because the last check always does `'' == ''`.

`new_string` is empty, and all thats ever added to it is another empty string `''`. Then you assign `backwards_string` to `''` as well.

There are other problems with your code, but since you are not looking for a full solution try to go through line by line and ask youself what's actually going on. For example, that `markList` looks redundant.

Comment: oh thx lol, i just joined... didnt know u needed to close it.

Comment: wait no, i got another problem

Comment: ill post another question then answer the two together later.